# Where Year In list of years Laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, where-in

What I want to do is something like this :

```
$listOfYears = Invoice::pluck('year') ; // [ 2001, 2002, 2003 ]
$products = Product::whereYearIn('purchase_date',$listOfYears)->get();
```

the field purchase_date is type `date` so you can't just use `whereIn`, you need to apply `whereYear` 1st, then `whereIn`.

Obviously this won't work because `whereYearIn` doesn't exist ...

I did this in the most slow & ugly way possible :

```
$listOfYears = Invoice::pluck('year') ; // [ 2001, 2002, 2003 ]
$products = Product::all()->filter(function($prod) {
     return in_array( date('Y',strtotime($prod->purchase_date)) , $listOfYears );
});
```

So I am asking if there is a way to achieve this ?
Also if the years could be preloaded in the same query with the method `with` it would be very optimized too.

**Note:**
This could be done easily in MySQL directly

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE YEAR('purchase_date') in ( SELECT year FROM invoices ) ;
```

Comment: is there a way to do `$products = Product::whereIn('YEAR(purchase_date)',$listOfYears)->get();` ?

Comment: you really want the `where in`? because you can do a scope with a `foreach` by the `years`  and do a `$query->orWhereYear('purchase_date', $year);`

Comment: @francisco that's avery good suggestion and this exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: check if does the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a scope on Product model like this:

```
public function scopeWhereYearIn($query, array $years)
{
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        $query->orWhereYear('purchase_date', $year);
    }
}
```

Then use it as: `Product::whereYearIn($years)->get();`

See here more about scopes on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereRaw()` function in laravel eloquent. In raw query use `extarct()` part of MySQL it will return the year from date.

```
$products = Product::whereRaw('extract(year from purchase_date) = ?', $listOfYears)->get();
```

Comment: Why you have used extract ?

Comment: It gives year/month from date. refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-extract

Comment: But there is different methods to extract month and year from date, Which one is efficient one and best practice

Comment: Both are same. There is absolutely no difference between the two, in performance or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$products = Product::whereRaw("YEAR('purchase_date') in ?", $listOfYears)->get();
```

Update

```
$products = Product::whereRaw("YEAR(purchase_date) in ?", $listOfYears)->get();
```